# Eclipse, new activity on button click

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, import

I'm a beginner but I would like to modify an older project.
On the Preferences Activity, there are already few buttons, but I would like to add a new button, which, when clicked, opens a new Activity and shows an image only.

For this I declared this new activity in the Manifest:

```
<activity
  android:name=".VisualHelpActivity"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</activity>
```

I declared the button on the associated xml layout:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button_visualhelp"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:onClick="visual_help"
  android:text="Visual Help" />
```

I created the new VisualHelp layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/visualhelp_image"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      android:src="@drawable/guide" />
```

Declared its new VisualHelpActivity java file:

```
public class VisualHelpActivity extends TranslatableActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_visualhelp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.visual_help, menu);
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void refreshLanguage() {
    }
}
```

… and now I’m supposed to connect it all together in the "main" PreferencesActivity, which looks as follows:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends TranslatableActivity {

    public static String url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin....";

    ImageView donate;

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                    onBackPressed();
                    return true;
            default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);

            donate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_donate);
            donate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            donate(v);
                    }
            });

            Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.combo_language);
            Lang[] languages = LanguageUtil.Lang.values();

            s.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Lang>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, languages));
            s.setSelection(getPosition(languages, LanguageUtil.getLanguage()), true);
    }

    private int getPosition(Object[] objs, Object item) {
            for (int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
                    if (objs[i] == item)
                            return i;
            }
            return -1;
    }

    public void update(View v) {
            Maintenance.downloadDB(this, new onFinishListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                            LanguageUtil.loadLanguage(PreferencesActivity.this);
                    }
            });
    }

    public void copy(View v) {
            Maintenance.copyDB(this, new onFinishListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                            LanguageUtil.loadLanguage(PreferencesActivity.this);
                    }
            });
    }

    public void save(View v) {
            LanguageUtil.saveLanguage(this,
                            (Lang) ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.combo_language))
                                            .getSelectedItem());
            LanguageUtil.loadLanguage(this);
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
    }

    public void donate(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
    }

    public void cancel(View v) {
            finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void refreshLanguage() {
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button_update)).setText(LanguageUtil
                            .getDeviceLabel(LanguageUtil.dev_update));
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.language_label))
            .setText(LanguageUtil.getDeviceLabel(LanguageUtil.dev_language));
    }

}
```

According to [androidbegin.com](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-button-click-new-activity-example/), I should add this code into the PreferencesActivity java file (code above):

```
Button button;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_visualhelp);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_visualhelp);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(PreferencesAtivity.this,
        VisualHelpActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

The only problem is that if I try to add this new `public void`, multiple marker errors pop up, and if I try to include all below somewhere else, my app fails to work. So, can anyone help me out where and how to include this code part to make it work?

Comment: Is your button in the VisualHelpActivity XML file or the PreferencesActivity XML file?

Comment: By the way just a friendly piece of advice. If you have a decent machine use Android Studio. It is also great if you have an Intel processor, because the new emulator(in the bleeding edge builds) is amazing.

Comment: my button is on the PreferencesActivity xml and should trigger VisualHelpActivity xml,

Comment: i cannot use Android studio, because for that i need to migrate my project and im not that good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the code inside oncreate method like this in your PreferencesActivity class:-

```
Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);

donate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_donate);
donate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        donate(v);
    }
});


button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_visualhelp);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(PreferencesAtivity.this,
    VisualHelpActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.combo_language);
Lang[] languages = LanguageUtil.Lang.values();

s.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Lang>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, languages));
s.setSelection(getPosition(languages, LanguageUtil.getLanguage()), true);
}
```

Comment: its not good, i filled the code from androidbegin.com related to how i understand it, but it seems i didn't understood very well, because when i try to fill as you recommended it, i got the error that `Intent myIntent = new Intent(PreferencesAtivity.this,
    VisualHelpActivity.class);` PreferencesAtivity cannot be resolved to a type. I also want to ask about `public void onClick(View arg0)`, that arg0 what it means?

Comment: its a view that you pressed

Comment: my bad, wasn't pay attention to code correctness and copy/paste your code without checking it. I missed a "c" from `PreferencesAtivity.this`, so the code is compiling correctly now, but the button still not recall the new activity (no error given, only the app crash.

Comment: that arg0 has any role in viewing the new activity?

Comment: as i mentioned, the new activity consist in showing an image only, the code above is correct for image "recall" activity?

Comment: nah arg0 dont have any role.it represent the pressed view.

Comment: my code start with `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and the one from the tutorial with `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` that can be a problem?